# How to Fourier transform two graph and find a function that make one similar to another in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, fft

I have daily data like below as a result.

[image: result data]

[image: prediction data]

And my daily prediction is like the one below most of the day.
I found a mild trend that value of Y-axis in my prediction where X-axis is between 0-3000 always need to be amplified much more..
How could I find a function that can close the prediction data to result data? I'd imagine I could do it if I Fourier transform both array but I also guess there would be a simpler way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to get as output is a kind of 'best fit' scaling function to match your output to your prediction. One straightforward approach would be to just calculate the difference of your output and prediction and then apply a smoothing algorithm of your choice to get a scaling function. (e.g. a [Savitzky Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) Filter)

Minimal example below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
data = np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(0, 0.2, 100) # a noisy sine function
prediction = x # line with slope 1, a bad initial fit

deviation = prediction - data

fit = savgol_filter(deviation, window_length=71, polyorder=2)
plt.plot(x, prediction-fit)
plt.plot(x, data)
```

play around with *window_length* and *polyorder* to find a suitable degree of noise for your dataset.